# Caffe Installation - NuGet packages for OpenCv 2.4 and OpenBlas 0.2.14 missing - throwing several build errors on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, caffe

I am an absolute beginner in Caffe and I am trying to build the Caffe solution on windows 10 on Visual Studio 2015 with OpenCV 3.1.0 on C++. I have been following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrzAF2sxHHM youtube link for reference.

These are the steps that I have followed till now:-

1.I have uninstalled OpenCv 2.4 from the Nuget Packages library and have installed opencv default build (Opencv 310) instead.

2.Also I have enabled the Nuget packages by going to Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources and have checked Microsoft and dot net option there.

3.Just FYI, I want to run in the CPU only mode (no GPU) and have changed the settings in CommonSettings.props as follows,

```
<CpuOnlyBuild> true </ CpuOnlyBuild>


<UseCuDNN > false </UseCuDNN>
```

4.I have also changed the BLAS configuration from default (atlas) to open since OpenBlas v 0.2.14.1 is installed in the Nuget packages.

```
# BLAS configuration (default = ATLAS) BLAS ?= open
```

I am still getting the following build errors-

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\..\NugetPackages\OpenCV.2.4.10\build\native\OpenCV.props.    libcaffe    C:\Users\AD355671\Downloads\caffe-master\caffe-master\windows\libcaffe\libcaffe.vcxproj 376 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\..\NugetPackages\OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1\build\native\openblas.targets.    caffe   C:\Users\AD355671\Downloads\caffe-master\caffe-master\windows\caffe\caffe.vcxproj   100
```

My questions are:-

1. Why is it still building with Opencv2.4 when I have uninstalled it and used Opencv3.10?
2. How do I resolve these build errors? Am I missing out setting any environment variables or any entry on the properties of config files(MakeFile.config and CommonSettings.props )?
3. Why is it not able to pick from openBlas?

Please help as I have been stuck with this for long. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve:

1. Uninstall "opencv default" from NuGetPackage
2. From the Tools-menu, select Library Package Manager and then click Package Manager Console.
3. Type "Install-Package OpenCV"
4. Rebuild all